# Trying to execute a basic pl/sql statement in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

So i wrote this basic procedure to learn pl/sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INPARAMHELLOWORLD
(
  p_name IN VARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('Hello' || p_name);
END;
```

I tried to execute it by typing:

```
exec INPARAMHELLOWORLD('Me');
```

The error I recive is

> line 1, column 7:
>
> identifier 'INPARAMHELLOWORLD' must be declared
>
> line 1, column 7:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> 1. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>
> *Action:

Any ideas?

Comment: You should check the `USER_ERRORS` view for compilation errors.  It will tell you what the error is, and on what line it appears.

Comment: Oh, and you might want to try having a slash on its own line after your procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound the stupidest answer, but I strongly doubt you created the package. (The code works fine on my 12c installation)

If you really did, try this to check if there are any errors on your procedure:

```
select *
from   user_errors
where  name = 'INPARAMHELLOWORLD'
```